# How to implement internationalization in shells in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.x

I've successfully implemented internationalization in a CakePHP 3.8 web application. However, in the shell environment of the same web application, internationalization does not work when sending emails. It only shows values of the default locale.

- checked content and authorization of po-file:

  ```
  src/Locale/de/default.po
  -rw-r--r--  1 www   wheel  9663 Jul 13 05:28 default.po
  ```
- default locale is the English language

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

**Shell:**

```
public function nl2locavores($name = 'Anonymous') {
    $this->loadModel('Crm');
    $rc = $this->Crm->nl2locavores();
    $this->out('lcvrShell nl2locavores:  number of emails send: ' . $rc);
}
```

**Model/Table/CrmTable.php:**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

class CrmTable extends Table
{
    public function nl2locavores() {
        I18n::setLocale('de');
        // ....
        $this->sndCrmEmail($nl_list);
    }

    private function sndCrmEmail($nl_list) {
        $email->setTemplate('newsletter2019');  
        $email->emailFormat('html');  
    }
}
```

**Template/Email/html/newsletter2019.ctp:**

```
echo __('Newsletter');
```

All Emails are sent in English although Locale is set to 'de'.

Comment: Putting the maybe a little too dumbed down code aside, there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong that might cause this. Clear the cache (`tmp/cache/persistent`), and if it still doesn't work, then you'll have to do some debugging to figure out where things start to go wrong (for example hook up a proper debugger, set a breakpoint at the `__()` call, and step through the code).

Comment: Thanks @ndm   Clearing the cache /tmp/cache/persistent solved this problem.